# Importing module via another module

Tags: python

In module A, I import module B. Then, in module C, I import module A. In module C, will I be able to use the content of module B implicitly via the import of module A, or will I have to explicitly import it into module C?

Comment: Implicitly works fine. It's like copy-pasting. Why did you not try this? It'd take you a minute.

Comment: [Python 3 - The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Answer (score 2):

That should work just fine. However, it would save you some trouble to explicitly import the module as well if only to keep track in your head when looking back at code

If you have any other questions about importing, try taking a gander to this article here

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

It should help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work.

I think however you'll have to do:

```
import moduleB
```

rather than:

```
from moduleB import methodX
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example down below to give you a start but really you should read the basic tutorial and give it a go first

```
#A.py

import B

def func_in_a():
    B.func_from_b


#C.py

import A

A.func_in_a():
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

If C imports A (C.py : `import A`) and A imports B (A.py : `import B`)  and in B you have a function

```
def funcb():
    return `foo`
```

you can call it from module C :

```
res = A.B.funcb()
```

and it will give `res = 'foo'`