# PYTHON - Imported module in subfolder imports its own local module

Tags: python, import

My question seems surely really basic, and may have been already asked/answered but I didn't have been able to find it. I found another topic about a similar problem ([Importing module via another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289887/importing-module-via-another-module)) but it doesn't treat it completely. The difference here is that the module is in a subfolder, and not it the same directory.

Here's the question, I have the given directory tree :

```
a.py
Folder
 |
 +-- b.py
 +-- c.py
```

And the files content:

```
$a.py
import Folder.b

$b.py
import c

$c.py
# noop
```

And the result when running a.py

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'
```

I assume that `import Folder.b` in `a.py` simply "copy-pastes" the line, so Python tries to search a `c` module in `a.py` directory. If that's right (or not), how to tell python to search for a module from the same directory than the imported module ?

Comment: have you added __init__.py file in that directory? put a blank __init__.py file and check

Comment: There isn't a __init__.py. But even after created it, it gives the same error about c.

Comment: what is there in the c.py file?

Comment: There's what I have written, literally no operation.

Answer (score 0):

This comes two years too late, but maybe it will help someone else.

If you change the import in **b.py** to:

```
$b.py
from . import c
```

it should work.