# Importing modules in another module, in a way that the parent module is being executed from its own path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine my files are like this:

```
.
└── a.ipynb
    └── folder1
        ├── b.py
        ├── c.py
        ├── folder2
            └── d.py
```

in `a.ipynb` b is imported like this:

```
from folder1.b import something
```

and in `b.py`, c and d are imported like this:

```
from c import something
from folder2.d import something
```

Previously there was no folder1, and `a.ipynb` was in the same place as `b.py`, so b was imported using `from b import something`, and everything was working correctly. Now I made folder1 and brought `a.ipynb` out, so I changed the way of Importing b, but I don't want to go inside b and change the way it is importing c and d too (practically impossible to do so).

That being said, is there a way that python opens all modules in a.ipynb as they are being executed from their own path?

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822522/python-imported-module-in-subfolder-imports-its-own-local-module) the Closest question to mine, but the answer requires changing files which I don't want to. Please let me know if it is not possible to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately the other question you linked is what you have to do. Once `b.py` and `c.py` are not local files in your current running directory, they need to be imported in a way that tells Python where to look for them.

Comment: Why can't you edit `b.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

In  `a.ipynb`, add:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("folder1")
```